# Java:Sorting an arraylist having linkedlist with the first element

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

Consider this arraylist with linkedlist objects
(are->1->3->7 , croco-> 4 ->1 , bat ->3->8).
Now I have to sort the arraylist in java in ascending order considering the first element of linkedlist contained in arraylist.
      There is a method Collections.sort() but it is useful when objects are strings.
What to apply in this situation?
The final list should look something like this
(are->1->3->7 , bat ->3->8 , croco-> 4 ->1 )

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort();` has an overloaded method that takes a comparator as well. So you want something like this:

```
Collections.sort(lists, (o1, o2) ->
        o1.get(0).compareTo(o2.get(0))
);
```

Or if you can use Java 8, there is a  default `sort` method in `List` interface:

```
lists.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.get(0)));
```

Comment: Since my arraylist identifier is arr, I am using what you said above arr.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> o.get(0))); but it is showing error can't find symbol get()

Comment: Is your data list of lists?

Comment: It is linked lists inside an ArrayList, ArrayList<LinkedList> arr = new ArrayList<LinkedList>()

Comment: Does your ``LinkedList`` has a method for getting the first element?

Comment: Yes arr.get(j).getFirst() where j is a index of arraylist, but we should be in for loop then.

Comment: Collections.sort(arr, (o1, o2) ->
        o1.getFirst().compareTo(o2.getFirst()));  Why I am getting error in compareTo, it says cannot find compareTo()

Comment: That's for strings,  what type does your LinkedList has?

Comment: My linked list first element is string but other are integers, I only want to compare the first element of linked list with first element of other linked list for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Without much context, I might be wrong. However, from my judgement if you're using your own objects which contain an identifier (are, croco and bat), and a linkedlist(numbers), then you can use the following solution.

> Your class needs to implement the Comparable Interface
>   You need to override the compareTo() method
>   Collections.sort() should sort your objects in ascending order.

```
public class Example implements Comparable {
    private String identifier;
    private List<Integer> list;

    // constructors
    // getters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object other){ 
    if(this.list.head() > other.list.head()) return 1; 
    if(this.list.head() < other.list.head()) return -1;
    else return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I applied what you said, but getting an error as it is saying in other.list that cannot find symbol , other is of type Object.

Comment: You need a getter function for your list, otherwise you have to make your list object public.

Have a function: 

public List<Integer> getList() {
    return this.list;
}

And then in the compareTo function, replace the 
other.list.head() with 
other.getList().get(0)

Comment: public class invertedindexcreate implements Comparable{
  private LinkedList<String> lisst;
    
    public LinkedList<String> getLisst(){
   return this.lisst;
    }
    

   @Override
   public int compareTo(LinkedList<String> other){
   if(this.lisst.getFirst()> other.lisst.getFirst()) return 1; 
    if(this.lisst.getFirst() < other.lisst.getFirst()) return -1;
    else return 0;
   } I wrote this and it shows errors.

Comment: So, now I implemented like this,public class invertedindexcreate implements Comparable<invertedindexcreate>{
  private LinkedList<String> lisst;
    
    public LinkedList<String> getLisst(){
   return this.lisst;
    }
    

   
   public int compareTo(invertedindexcreate other){
   return (this.lisst.getFirst()).compareTo(other.getLisst().getFirst());
   }             Now, in main method compareTo cannot be still found Collections.sort(arr, (o1, o2) ->
        o1.getFirst().compareTo(o2.getFirst()));